# How do I prevent nginx from changing my request URL in Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to build my Angular website in a Docker, that works too but whenever the website makes a request the URL is changed from http://url_to_api to http://localhost:8080/url_to_api.

I am very new to NGINX and docker and have tried many different configurations, but none have worked.

Also I get the error in the browser:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  /assets/js/env.js
```

Is nginx blocking that?

Here is my basic nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

And here the docker file

```
#stage 1
FROM node:12-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/webapp /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
#To provide environment variables in angular 
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/js/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/js/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Comment: is your website only has static pages?. only then nginx will work properly.

Comment: No, it has also dynamic pages. What should I use instead?

Comment: use the below dockerfile i answered and create your image. Serving pages from node will take care of dynamic pages like you run in your local machine. Also look into the url for step by step approach

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your configuration builds only a basic server which should not be used for production and that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad that it helps, Yes the dockerFile is very basic and can host dynamic pages and solve the problem you are facing. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but it does not help since it cannot be used for production.

Comment: okay, if your expectation is production dockerfile, then can you rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have now found my error. The config files are ok, but made a very stupid mistake, my script at the end of the docker file has exchanged the API URL but I forgot to specify HTTP at the beginning of the URL and so Nginx has requested the URL on the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create image based on the official Node 10 image from dockerhub
FROM node:10

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package*.json /app/

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /app/

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Check the steps here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/create-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-and-docker-compose
To learn and build docker for angular2 client